# Stripe connect usage for splitting payments

Tags: stripe-payments

I've got a question about the Stripe Connect API. We want to split every payment. It is everytime the same. Some money should be transferred to another Stripe account. Is it usefuly or the right way to realize this over Stripe Connect?

Maybe it is easier to send the money via E-Mail like paypal? - Does Stripe offer something like this?

Because when I want to use the Stripe Connect functionality the other account has to be connected, right?

What is the best way?

Comment: Check out Transfers: https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: stripe.com/docs/api/transfers